# Reactjs change state value from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
<input value={this.state.date)} onChange={this.handleForm} type="text" />
<DatePickerFa date={this.state.date} />
```

I pass date to `DatePickerFa`

And this is my `DatePickerFa`:

```
changeYear(){
        this.props.date = "...";
}

<span onClick={this.changeYear}>CHANGE</span>
```

I want into changeYear, change the this.state.date

Important:

I dont want use function in parent like this code:

```
handler(value) {
    this.setState({
        date: value
    })
}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't mutate the state. You have to use setState to update the state.

Comment: That's just not how React works. You could use a context or other state handling mechanism like Redux to change how the state is interacted with, however.

Comment: "I dont want use function in parent like this code" I'm curious as to why this is important to you- the solution here is to do exactly this, and [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the DatePickerFa component to the parent component that contains the input and the DatePickerFa. You're trying to both pass a prop down and then mutate it, but in React the data should mostly flow in one direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function to the child:

```js
<DatePickerFa 
  date={this.state.date} 
  setDate={newDate => { this.setState({date: newDate}) }}
/>
```

Now in your child:

```js
<span 
  // pass a new value to the callback function:
  onClick={e => this.props.setDate(e.target.value)} // or whatever
>
  CHANGE
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking one major principle of React.
**Props are immutable** that is.

```
this.props.date = "...";
```

This can't be done.
Instead, **you need to update the state using setState** in order to change that date.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use setState function.
it will look like this:

```js
changeYear(){
        setState({ this.props.date: "..." })
}
```

And also don't forget to bind component, add this line to your constructor whit state:

```js
this.changeYear = this.changeYear.bind(this)
```